# set text color for each custom adapter from a listView

Tags: android

I want to make a diable switch that can instantly gray out and disable a list of options from a listView, but I am not sure how to acchieve this with a CustomAdapter for each single row. With only textview it should be easy to set it with a onclick method, but can I also do that with a CustomAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of abstract because it doesn't have any code samples and no specific problem as well. So my answer will be abstract as well.

To achieve this set a listener on your switch. Once it's clicked, update the model that is used for displaying your adapter items.

If you need to update all items in the list, then you can add a `boolean` variable to the adapter class. Use this variable in your `getView()` method to decide whether the item should be grayed out or not. When the value is changed, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter object. It will trigger redrawing all items in the list.

If you need to update only specific items, then add this `boolean` variable to the item model itself. Iterate over collection and set this flag where needed. All other logic is the same - use this variable in `getView()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.